# how to return a connection in c3p0

Tags: java, c3p0

I am using c3p0 - ComboPooledDataSource. I am initializing once as below.

```
private void init() {
cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
cpds.setDriverClass(driverName);
cpds.setJdbcUrl(url);
cpds.setUser(userName);
cpds.setPassword(pwd);
}
```

I am getting a connection from the pool as below

```
public synchronized Connection getLocalConnection(String ipAddr)
    throws SQLException {
return cpds.getConnection();
}
```

But i am not sure whether its the right way to return the connection back to the pool when i finish executing a query. I guess the

```
conn.close()
```

just returns the connection back to the pool instead of REALLY CLOSING the connection.
Am i correct or is there any other way around? Pls help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is initializing code

```
private DataSource init() {

    DataSource unpooled = DataSources.unpooledDataSource(DB_URL, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

    Map<String, Object> overrideProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    overrideProps.put("maxPoolSize", MAX_POOL_SIZE);
    overrideProps.put("minPoolSize", MIN_POOL_SIZE);

    return DataSources.pooledDataSource(unpooled, overrideProps);
}
```

And you get connection from DataSource.

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return dataSource.getConnection();
}
```

And to close the connection just call close() method.

```
connection.close();
```