# How to return connection to pool in c3p0?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

Some one asked this question earlier but still I have same query..
[how to return a connection in c3p0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754461/how-to-return-a-connection-in-c3p0)`

My Sample code:

```
static HashMap<String,ComboPooledDataSource> c3p0PoolsMap=new HashMap<>();
public static void initC3p0ConnPool(String dbUrl,String driver,String userId,String password){
    ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    try {
        cpds.setDriverClass(driver);
        cpds.setJdbcUrl(dbUrl);
        cpds.setUser(userId);                                  
        cpds.setPassword(password);                                  
        // the settings below are optional -- c3p0 can work with defaults
        cpds.setMinPoolSize(2);                                     
        cpds.setAcquireIncrement(5);
        cpds.setMaxPoolSize(5);
    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } 
    c3p0PoolsMap.put(dbUrl,cpds);
}
```

second method:

```
public void connPoolTest(String dbUrl, String driver,String userId,String password){
        initC3p0ConnPool(dbUrl, driver, userId, password);
        ComboPooledDataSource cp1=c3p0PoolsMap.get(dbUrl);
        Connection c=null;
        try {

            System.out.println("getInitialPoolSize : "+cp1.getInitialPoolSize());//3
            c=cp1.getConnection();
            System.out.println(" getNumBusyConnections "+ cp1.getNumBusyConnections());///1
            System.out.println(" getNumConnections "+ cp1.getNumConnections());//3
            java.sql.Statement s=c.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("select * from table1 where activity_date>sysdate-1");
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(c!=null){
                try {
                    c.close();
                    System.out.println(" getNumBusyConnections "+ cp1.getNumBusyConnections());///still showing 1
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }
        }
    }
```

After connection close numOfBusyConnection still showing 1.
Please suggest how to return connection to pool after use.

Comment: and if you call this 5 times - does it show `5` ?  I am guess that  the close maybe takes some time.

Comment: yeah I also think so, close method is taking some time. I ran program in debug mode and found it working fine.